# margin setting is invalid for set the link element horizontally center

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a web page. The link with the image need to be horizontal aligned to center.
On the .css file, I've wrote (more specifically in the `.ad` class , `margin:40 auto 50 auto`), but the element still aligned to left. Why?

```css
/* style */

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 520px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  background-color: purple;
}

.nav {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.ad {
  display: block;
  width: 1198px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 40 auto 50 auto;
  /*margin:0 auto;*/
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}


/* common.css */

.a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.headerbg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

.main {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
}

.mt40 {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
index.html

<!-- 
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  -->

<body>
  <!-- header start -->
  <div class="headerbg">

  </div>
  <!-- header end -->
  <!-- banner start -->
  <div class="banner">

  </div>
  <!-- banner end -->
  <!-- nav start -->
  <div class="nav">

  </div>
  <!-- nav end  -->
  <!-- main 1st content start  -->
  <div class="main mt40">
    1 content
  </div>
  <!-- main 1st content end -->
  <!-- main 2nd content start -->
  <div class="main mt40">
    2 content
  </div>
  <!-- main 2nd content end -->
  <a href="#" class="ad">
    <img src="#" width="1198" height="153">
  </a>
</body>
```

Comment: I wouldn't call the html code 'program'... It is just a code.

Comment: which element do you want to make it horizontal centre?

Comment: `margin: 40 auto 50 auto;`
40 or 50 what?

Comment: this element need to be horizontal center    <a href="#" class="ad">
            <img src="#" width="1198" height="153" >
       </a>

Comment: 40 and 50 means margin-top:40px, margin-bottom:50px, is it right

Answer (score 1):

I add margin property value in pixel. Please try to replace the code below.

```
.ad {
  display: block;
  width: 1198px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 40px auto 50px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
margin: 40px auto 50px auto;
```

margin: 40px auto 50px auto;

- top margin is 40px
- right margin is auto
- bottom margin is 50px
- left margin is auto

left and right margins set to auto will align your item to the center